# How to properly configure mock dependencies for testing Web Api (ASP.NET Core) controllers using Autofac

Tags: testing, asp.net-core, autofac, xunit

I'm using ASP.NET Core (2.0) with `Autofac`, and a  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer` for integration testing. However, for some test scenarios, I would like to inject some service mocks instead of the implementations loaded in `ConfigureContainer` method (as described here: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#quick-start-with-configurecontainer).

Example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .ConfigureServices(s => s.AddAutofac())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    ...
    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterModule(new Modules.ApiModule());
    }
    ...
}
```

And the test class:

```
public class BasicControllerTests
{
    TestServer server;
    HttpClient client;

    public BasicControllerTests()
    {
        var resellerRepo = new Mock<IResellerProvider>();
        resellerRepo.Setup(a => a.Query())
            .Returns(new[] {
            new Model.Reseller
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Code = "R1",
                Name = "Reseller 1"
            }
            }.AsQueryable());

        // How to inject mock properly in the lines below?

        server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices(a => a.AddAutofac())
            .UseStartup<Startup>());

        client = server.CreateClient();
    }
   ...
```

What I would like to do is to use the `TestServer` with all the dependencies as they are, but just the `IResellerProvider` mocked as in the test example. What is the best way to accomplish that? Of course, I could create a `TestStartup` class for this exact case, but I would like to know what is the proper way to handle this situation.

Comment: Create a parent generic class to setup all the providers, expressions .. and make your tests inherit it.

Comment: Last service registered overrides any previous registration. So let the normal service configuration go to completion and then configure your mocks

Comment: @AhmedRagheb: I would like to avoid that, since for various scenarios, I would potentially end up with many startup classess,

Comment: @Nkosi Yes, my question is how do I do that? After I do `ConfigureServices` on a TestServer, how can I register more things?

Comment: @itim why yo will end up with many statups classes ?

Comment: @Item you do them within that function ie `.ConfigureServices(services => { services.AddAutofac(); services.AddTransient<IResellerProvider>(p => resellerRepo.Object); })`

Comment: I would still advise using a test startup which would be simpler

Comment: Yes, it would, but I can imagine that (for integration tests), for some scenarios I want to use a mock for just one thing, for the others a mock for another thing, and so on. I was wondering if there's any way to use Autofac itself (so I can also use, say, PropertiesAutowired, etc). Apart from that, this solution is fine, I would vote it up if you offer it as an answer. EDIT: However, it doesn't seem to work :( The service resolved is still the one defined in `ConfigureContainer`.

Comment: make the `ConfigureContainer` virtual and override it in a derived class and use that class as startup.

Comment: This is similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54107886/mocking-and-resolving-autofac-dependency-in-integration-test-in-aspnetcore-with

Comment: Isn't the `.ConfigureTestServices(services => { })` method on WebHostBuilder supposed to deal with it? It doesn't work on my case and that's why I would like to know whether you accomplished it. Please provide details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround that works just fine and lets you inject any other dependency in .net core api.
You will have this standard code to start up in your tests

```
var clientFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>();
var client = clientFactory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
{

}));

var _httpClient = client.CreateClient();
```

Now you need to pass to .ConfigureTestServices an Action and you can use this to remove the registration you have on the normal app startup and add another one that lets say it's a fake one.This in possible because if you look with debugger on services you will see that all those you registered are presend and you will just need to replace the ones you want to moke.Here is a simple example that I used

```
RemoveVehicleServiceRegistrationFrom(services);
services.AddScoped<IVehicleService, FakeVehicleService>();
```

In the Remove method you just need to find and remove old registration.Something like this

```
private static void RemoveVehicleServiceRegistrationFrom(IServiceCollection services)
{
     var vehicleService = services.Single(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(IVehicleService));
     services.Remove(vehicleService);
}
```

Final version looks like this

```
private HttpClient _httpClient;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    var clientFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>();
    var client = clientFactory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            RemoveVehicleServiceRegistrationFrom(services);
            services.AddScoped<IVehicleService, FakeVehicleService>();
        }));

    var _httpClient = client.CreateClient();
}

private static void RemoveVehicleServiceRegistrationFrom(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var vehicleService = services.Single(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(IVehicleService));
    services.Remove(vehicleService);
}
```