# Mocking and resolving Autofac dependency in integration test in AspNetCore with TestServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, autofac, asp.net-core-testhost

I'm using AspNetCore 2.2
Following (moreless) the docs here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I am using Autofac, my Startup class has the following methods:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder) //this is where things can be registered directly with autofac and runs after ConfigureServices
public void Configure(...) //the method called by runtime
```

The way I use Autofac, as recommended by its docs, is by having `Program.cs like this`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
            {
                var env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;
                config
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            });
}
```

I am now using TestServer for my test project where I want to use the real Startup class. But I would like to modify one of the dependencies.

I have seen that there is a method available on `WebHostBuilder` to `.ConfigureTestServices(services => {});`

so I tried the following:

```
public abstract class ComponentTestFeature
    : Feature
{
    protected HttpClient HttpClient { get; }

    protected ComponentTestFeature()
    {
        var configuration =
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Test.json")
                .Build();

        var webHostBuilder =
            new WebHostBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())
                .ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddScoped<IEventStoreManager, MockEventStoreManager>();
                })
                .UseConfiguration(configuration)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();

        var server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);
        HttpClient = server.CreateClient();
        var myService = server.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<IEventStoreManager>();
    }
}
```

As you can see I want to use a `MockEventStoreManager` implementation for `IEventStoreManager` so that this is the implementation that should be resolved by the container. However this is not working as expected and myService resolved is the original implementation, the real one, not the mock one.

Does anybody know how could I achieve what I want?

UPDATE 1: 
After more investigation I had to create an issue on github AspNetCore because the extension method is executed before the ConfigureContainer, therefore I cannot really override autofac dependencies nor retrieve autofac container later on.
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6522

UPDATE 2:
Just FYI, this is how the Startup.cs looks like. As you can see all the dependencies but mvc are registered in autofac's container.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}

// This is where things can be registered directly with autofac and runs after ConfigureServices, so it will override it
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<EventStoreManager>().As<IEventStoreManager>();
}
```

and what I want to do is to use `MockEventStoreManager` implementation for `IEventStoreManager` in my tests, so I need to override (from my test project) that Autofac's registration in a nice way.

Comment: Where in the flow is the original `IEventStoreManager` registered? `ConfigureServices` or directly with the container in `ConfigureContainer`?

Comment: In `ConfigureContainer`, with autofac container

Comment: Just like `ConfigureTestServices`, there is a `ConfigureTestContainer<TContainer>` that can be used to directly manipulate the container. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Register the mocked implementation with the container builder for the test using [ConfigureTestContainer](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Hosting/TestHost/src/WebHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L51)

```
//...
.ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())
.ConfigureTestContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder => {
    builder.RegisterType<MockEventStoreManager>().As<IEventStoreManager>();
})
//...
```

This should avoid getting the actual implementation that is added by `Startup.ConfigureContainer` as

> If more than one component exposes the same service, **Autofac will use the last registered component as the default provider of that service**:
>
> Reference [Default Registrations](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#default-registrations)

`ConfigureTestContainer` is invoked after the `Startup.ConfigureContainer` so the last registration with the mock would be the default provider of the service.

Comment: For Asp .Net Core 3.0+ or Generic hosting `services.AddAutofac()` does not work. From Autofac code documentation: "ONLY FOR PRE-ASP.NET 3.0 HOSTING. THIS WON'T WORK FOR ASP.NET CORE 3.0+ OR GENERIC HOSTING."

Answer (score 9):

Adding to Nkosi's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54243337/9449426), I'd like to mention that `ConfigureTestContainer` does not work with the generic host [recommended over the web host by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1) as of .NET Core 3.0. There is however a [workaround proposed by Alistair Evans from the Autofac team](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/1207#issuecomment-701961371). Unfortunately, it relies on the deprecated `IStartupConfigureContainerFilter` that has been removed in .NET 5.0.

This means that currently in .NET 5.0 there is no way to mock dependencies injected by an external DI container in integration tests when using the generic host.

Luckily, David Fowler from the ASP.NET team [is looking into the issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14907#issuecomment-592102145).

Comment: In the meantime, the answer here worked for me to mock Autofac dependencies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76120434/3203786

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options:

- Have a custom implementation of your dependency in your testserver
  project
- Implement and manually register a mocked implementation of your dependency with a nugget like "Moq"

Comment: I have a custom implementation of the interface in my testserver project. It's in fact using Moq internally not to use a real connection to an external system. The problem is that I cannot tell my application, when testing, that the concrete implementation to be used is the mocked one instead the one registered on Startup.cs' ConfigureContainer. In other words, I am unable to override autofac's container from TestServer