# How to override a service in Autofac container using WebApplicationFactory

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, autofac, .net-6.0

I'm writing some integration testing using WebApplicationFactory. I use Autofac as my dependency resolver. In my test, I'm trying to override one of the registration so I can mock one of the dependency. It's pretty simple using the aspnetcore default ConfigureServices method :

```
public static RestClient GetClient(Func<IDependency> dependencyFactory)
{
   var application = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>().WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
   {
       builder.ConfigureServices(s =>
       {
            s.AddTransient<Func<IDependency>>(s=>dependencyFactory);
       });
    });
    return GetRestClient(application.CreateClient());
}
```

But, what I'm trying to do is to do the same thing using the Autofac ContainerBuilder. Something that would look like :

```
public static RestClient GetClient(Func<IDependency> dependencyFactory)
{
   var application = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>().WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
   {
       builder.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(containerBuilder =>
       {
            containerBuilder.Register<IDependency>(c=>dependencyFactory()).InstancePerDependency();
       });
    });
    return GetRestClient(application.CreateClient());
}
```

Any of you know how I can do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: The contents of [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14907) may help. Also, note `ConfigureContainer` won't get called unless you also `UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())`.

Comment: Thanks. [This](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14907#issuecomment-850407104) was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but I found the [article](https://andrewlock.net/converting-integration-tests-to-net-core-3/).

TL;DR

You have to inherit from `WebApplicationFactory<T>`  and override `CreateHost` method.

So for me it looks like

```
public class MyWebApplicationFactory: WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(ConfiguresContainer);
        return base.CreateHost(builder);
    }

    private void ConfiguresContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //add something extra to your container here
    }
}
```